# How to add UINavigationBar in an UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar, exc-bad-access

I have an `UIViewController` class(Say it is XXX). I present this view controller as modally by the code..

```
XXX *xxx = [ [XXX alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:xxx animated:YES];
[xxx release];
```

I want to add a navigation bar on the top of the XXX view. So I used `UINavigationBar` object in XXX's `loadView` method.

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [ [UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
[self.view addSubview:navBar];
[navBar release];
```

But, It throws an error as "EXC_BAD_ACCESS". Any help...?

Thanks

Comment: Try to add Navigationbar to XXX view in XIB

Comment: If u use Navigation than u have to push it...i.e. 'pushViewController' has to be used instead presentModalViewController..

Answer (score 17):

**OPTION-1:**

Try adding navigation bar from the XIB of viewController called XXX.

**OPTION-2:**

Add a UINavigationController and present it modally.

Replace your code :

```
XXX *xxx = [[XXX alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:xxx animated:YES];
[xxx release];
```

with this code:

```
XXX *xxx = [[XXX alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:xxx];
[self presentModalViewController:navigation animated:YES];
[navigation release];
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks.. So, We can not add UINavigationBar without creating UINavigationController here. Am I right?

Comment: @Rajkanth: Yes, probably that should be the case as far as I know. As you are getting a "EXC_BAD_EXCESS" when you try adding it programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code with:

```
    XXX *xxx = [[ [XXX alloc] init]autorelease];
    [self presentModalViewController:xxx animated:YES];

    UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:xxx];
    [self presentModalViewController:navigation animated:YES];
    [navigation release];
```

I think it will solve your "`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`" problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this by adding toolbar at the top of the view. In many cases i have seen for poping MODAL controller this is nice solution. but if you want to navigate more controllers from MODAL controller then you should use UINavigationController.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you do it like this:

```
XXX *xxx = [[XXX alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:xxx];
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
[xxx release];
[navigationController release];
```